# Django Template to make a list to be sent as post

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make an MCQ quiz and I have used the following code in a template:

```
{% for MCQ in mcq %}
<input type="radio" name="MCQ" value="{{ MCQ.id }}">{{ MCQ.MCQ_Text }}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that I want to use `MCQ_list = request.POST[MCQ]` to access it as a list. How do I make a list in the template? Alternatively, is there a better way to approach this?

Edit:
The mcq is nested inside

```
{% for Questions, mcq in Quest_dic.items %}
<br>
{{ Questions.Question_Text }}
{% for MCQ in mcq %}
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="ListOrAlternateHere" value="{{ MCQ.id }}">{{ MCQ.MCQ_Text }}
{% endfor %}
<hr> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: When the input type is a radio, when will the list ever have more than one entry?

Answer (score 0):

change your input to `type=checkbox`. This will let you read the checked items as a list in python:

`mcq_list = request.POST.getlist('MCQ')`